# Search position in complex json/array to update with javascript (angularjs or pure)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to search a value in my complex json/array and I need to do an update in object. My json/array is:

```
var myArray = [{
            "id": 5424,
            "description": "xxxxxxxx",
            "children": [{
                 "id": 8756,
                 "description": "yyyyyyy",
                 "Children": [{
                      "id": 8759,
                      "description": "zzzzzzz",
                      "Children": [{}]
                  }]
             }]
        },
        {
            "id": 5675,
            "description": "bbbbbbb",
            "Children": [{}]
        }];
```

How do I do it? I tried using `indexOf`, `find`, `map` but not got!

Comment: What value do you need to search/update?

Comment: You put jquery tag, you want a jquery solution?

Comment: I am using angularjs but jquery can be a solution too

Comment: For example I need to search the object with id = 8759

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a recursive function (pure javascript):

```
function updatePerson(id, propToUpdate, value) {
    var person = findPerson(id, myArray);
    if (person) {
        person[propToUpdate] = value;
    }
}

function findPerson(id, children) {
    var found;
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        var child = children[i];

        if (child.id == id) {
            found = child;
            break;
        } else if (child.children && child.children.length) {
            found = findPerson(id, child.children);
            if (found) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return found;
}
```

See for example [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jq8fu2n2/) in angular